# Definition for a trajectory in phase-space

Tags: definition, phase-space

When we say "a trajectory in phase space", when the parameter is time, do we mean the set of points in phase-space corresponding to a continuous segment in time? Does it have to be continuous? Does it matter if the segment in time is close or open?

Comment: time is continuous in  QM, so the same will happen with the trajectory, unless you are dealing with some discrete theory

Comment: In CM trajectories are usually continuous and in QM it doesn't really make sense to talk about a trajectory. One can talk about paths in terms of the path integral, but there we have to take all possible paths into account.

Comment: 'Trajectory' can certainly refer to a discrete set of points, e.g. a random walk.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Start by making clear what are you talking about. CM? QM?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, we usually consider **time is continuous**, both in classical and quantum mechanics.
However if some theory´s time is discrete, then the phase space trajectory corresponds to that (discrete) set of points.
The **openness or closeness** of the segment of time is **irrelevant** as far as physical effects are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in a Dynamical System perspective, if a given dynamical system is modeled by a map the time is discrete (not continuous), e.g. Hénon map and Logistic map. In such case, the trajectory is discrete as well.